# Put flavor picture in ImageView of layout

Tags: android, image, layout, imageview

I have five flavors and five different pictures for every flavor,
How can I put this images to ImageView of layout?
For every build variant ImageView must take specific flavor image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just need to create a drawable folder for the flavours with specific files.

For example, the flavour 'black' will need a drawable folder in which all your black-background images will be stored.

In order to get it working, all resources must exist for all flavours so you won't need to change any part of your code.

You can find a quick guide here:
https://medium.com/@thiagolopessilva/the-handling-multiple-java-source-and-resources-using-flavors-on-gradle-18a4b581285b

Comment: Yes, I have created directors with files in every flavor but in which xml file I need write reference for this pictures?